# Excluding data from a pandas dataframe based on percentiles

Tags: python, pandas

I am having difficulties trying to use Python to remove some data outliers prior to producing a scatterplot. I have a n by 43 dataframe imported using pandas. I have figured out how to determine the thresholds for the outliers and applied this to the dataframe such that I now have some boolean values corresponding to whether the data should be included in the scatter plot or not. I am however stuck on how to use this information to exclude the appropriate data points.

My code so far:

```
def identify_outliers(self,parameters_file):
    data=pandas.read_csv(parameters_file)        #import data
    header=data.keys()                           #get header
    quantiles = data.quantile([0.25,0.75],1)     #determine thresholds for all data 
    for i in range(len(header)):
        qnt_i = quantiles[header[i]].as_matrix() #get handle to quantiles 
                                                 #for specific column of data
        #identify data points that fall outside this range   
        boolean_data=data[header[i]].between(qnt_i[0],qnt_i[1])  
        for j in range(len(boolean_data)): #attempt to use boolean values to filter
                                           #data to only include 'True' (doesn't work)
            if boolean_data[j]:
                print data[header[i]]
```

Here is a snippet of data that is imported using pandas.read_csv

```
(v1).Kcat   (v1).km     (v11).k1
1.22E-02    1.20E-02    1.72E-06
0.0122441   1.42E-02    1.61E-06
1.04E-02    1.01E-02    1.00E-06
0.0136581   0.0185623   5.01158
0.0113221   0.0221445   0.0785929
0.506949    0.01        1.35E-06
1.16567     0.0141031   168.078
0.01        0.0100055   1.25E-06
0.0351003   153.682     163.082
0.0129821   0.0164996   0.0560866
```

Does anybody have a suggestion as to how I can filter 'data' to remove all the values which do not fall within the specified range.

Comment: can you specify what columns are in your current df after running the code?  Specifically, show what columns are the raw data and the boolean column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a smaller dataframe based on just your first 5 rows.

```
df

         v1          v2          v3
0  0.012200    0.012000    0.000002
1  0.012244    0.014200    0.000002
2  0.010400    0.010100    0.000001
3  0.013658    0.018562    5.011580
4  0.011322    0.022145    0.078593
```

And here's mask that selects only values between the 25th and 75th percentiles.  Note that the syntax for this is somewhat precise so be careful with the parentheses and such.

```
 ( df > df.quantile(.25) ) & ( df < df.quantile(.75) )

      v1     v2     v3
0   True   True   True
1   True   True   True
2  False  False  False
3   True  False  False
4  False  False   True
```

This is column-based, btw.  I just glanced quickly at your code and couldn't easily tell if the percentile measures were intended per-column of for the combination of the 3 columns.  For the whole dataframe you can do:

```
( df > df.stack().quantile(.25) ) & ( df < df.stack().quantile(.75) )
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer I was looking for is:

```
def identify_outliers(self,parameters_file):
    data=pandas.read_csv(parameters_file)
    header=data.keys()
    quantiles = data.quantile([0.25,0.75],1) 
    cols=data.shape[1]
    rows=data.shape[0]
    boolean_data=[]
    for i in range(len(header)):
        qnt_i = quantiles[header[i]].as_matrix()
        print data[header[i]][(qnt_i[0]<data[header[i]])&(data[header[i]]<qnt_i[1])]
```

So very similar to JohnE's answer. Thanks for responding